# Tradingview only shows Quandl CFTC data for last week

Tags: pine-script

i'm using pine script to pull CFTC COT data into my indicator. However, I am noticing that the latest row of data is never pulled from CFTC - the indicator only shows last week's data.

CFTC data is released every Friday 3:30 PM EST. I am viewing this data on a Saturday - so am expecting to see data released in yesterday's report.

Here's the script i'm using (the outcome does not changes if I use resolution=D or W in the security function in pine script)

```
//@version=4
study("COT data bug", shorttitle="Bug demo", precision=0)

qticker =
     syminfo.root == "ES" ? "13874A" :
     syminfo.root == "NQ" ? "209742" :
     syminfo.root == "RTY" ? "239742":
     syminfo.root == "YM" ? "124603" :
     syminfo.root == "ZN" ? "043602" :
     syminfo.root

cot = "QUANDL:CFTC/" + qticker + "_FO_ALL|"
oi = security(cot + "0", "W", close)
asset_mgr_lg = security(cot + "4", "W", close)
asset_mgr_sh = security(cot + "5", "W", close)

plot(oi, title="Open Interest", color=color.black)  // output=232,089, expected=230,513
plot(asset_mgr_lg, title="asset_mgr_lg", color=color.blue) // output=71,131, expected=65,170
plot(asset_mgr_sh, title="asset_mgr_sh", color=color.red) // output=29,288, expected=31,260
```

Has anyone else also faced this problem? Any potential solutions?

Thanks!

[image: Data that shows up on the chart]
[image: Data that's expected on the chart]

Comment: I tried validating this with scripts that other people also published - and noticed the same problem.

Comment: Seems like the data shows when the market opens up the next week (on Sunday). Will observe this for a couple of weeks and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to try would be to use `lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on` in your `security()` calls. This may fix the problem in the realtime bar, but will OTOH make your calls use future data on historical bars, where you will need to use the form you are currently using to avoid the lookahead bias.

If using lookahead on is indeed the solution, you could use code like this:

```
oiH           = security(cot + "0", "W", close)
asset_mgr_lgH = security(cot + "4", "W", close)
asset_mgr_shH = security(cot + "5", "W", close)
oiR           = security(cot + "0", "W", close, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
asset_mgr_lgR = security(cot + "4", "W", close, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
asset_mgr_shR = security(cot + "5", "W", close, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

oi            = 0.
asset_mgr_lg  = 0.
asset_mgr_sh  = 0.
if barstate.islast
    oi            := oiR
    asset_mgr_lg  := asset_mgr_lgR
    asset_mgr_sh  := asset_mgr_shR
else
    oi            := oiH
    asset_mgr_lg  := asset_mgr_lgH
    asset_mgr_sh  := asset_mgr_shH
```

Comment: Hi PineCoders-LucF, thanks for sharing that. Yes, that did help. The ultimate answer was to wait for Sunday - so when Futures open for /ES, Sunday forms a candle which starts showing the latest COT information.